# when clicked again, I want the color to be gone.(like/hate button, every thing works but if i click like button twice I want the color to be gone)

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I have two like and hate buttons. 
It almost works as I want, when I click the button like it turns blue. if I click hate then the button hate turns blue while the button like goes back to its original state.
But only problem is if I click "like" twice, then the like button should go back to its original state. I don't know how to achieve this task.

I currently have this,

```
<span class="thumb" style="padding-right:7px;"><a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=1" class="vote"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>like</a></span>   
<span class="thumb"><a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=0"  class="vote"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i>dislike</a></span>
<script>
$(".thumb a").click(function(e) {
  var target = $(e.target);
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.vote').removeClass('red blue')
  if (target.text() == 'love') {
    target.addClass('red');
  } else {
    target.addClass('blue');
  }
});
</script>
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/pvb9dnf7/ Or with your approach, you need to change the text as well to make condition work.. _(love => hate and vice-versa..)_

Comment: Not sure how it is working.when you click your target will be a tag & nowhere I am seeing target.text() == 'love' .If you create a jsfiddle that will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, 'love' should be like since there is only 'like' and 'dislike' in your code. And that 'like' should be red and 'dislike' should be blue.

```js
$(".thumb a").click(function(e) {
  var target = $(this),
  active = target.is('.red, .blue');
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.vote').removeClass('red blue');
  if (!active) {
    if (target.text() == 'like') {
      target.addClass('red');
    } else {
      target.addClass('blue');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="thumb" style="padding-right:7px;"><a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=1" class="vote"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>like</a></span>
<span class="thumb"><a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=0"  class="vote"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i>dislike</a></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".thumb a").click(function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    e.preventDefault();
    if (target.hasClass('blue')) {
        $('.vote').removeClass('blue');
    } else {
        $('.vote').removeClass('blue');
        target.addClass('blue');
    }
});
```